# How to implement remote_write or anything similar for Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, remote-write

> NOTE: I have started working on Promethus from couple days and very
> navie. Please correct me if I am wrong

Following is pictorial representation of how my IoT devices and Prometheus is detached completely

[image]

**Monitoring Server:**

```
Prometheus, Grafan, Loki, Prometheus Alerts
```

**Tech Servers (Publically accessable):**

```
API Server

Microfrontends (ReactJS, Android app, iOS app)

pgSQL Servers

MySQL Servers
```

**Devices (Publically not accessable):**

```
IoT Devices
```

**What works:**

I know that Prometheus works on pull model only.

Currently with Prometheus I am able to pull the metrics from our API Servers, SQL Servers and display them on Grafana dashboard accordingly.

**Problems facing:**

```
Our IoT devices does not have public IP address and can only be accessed via our in-house VPN server. We could have went with Prometheus Gateway to pull the metrics from our VPN server but because we would miss out couple of metrics like as per the Prometheus Pushgateway documentation and also if we plan to do so we have to implement our VPN server as Prometheus Pushgateway then it might bring down our whole VPN server and can make our VPN clients (IoT) devices unaccessable.
```

Is there any endpoint in Prometheus that we can push the metrics? I also got to know about **remote_write** feature but not able to find implementation examples.

Is there any other ways that we can monitor our IoT devices via Prometheus?

Following is snippet of how my Monitoring is setup and how prometheus is pulling the metrics

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  prometheus:
    container_name: prometheus
    image: prom/prometheus
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus:/etc/prometheus
      - ./prometheus-storage:/prometheus

  alertmanager:
    container_name: alertmanager
    image: prom/alertmanager
    ports:
      - 9093:9093
    volumes:
      - ./alertmanager:/config
      - ./alertmanager-storage:/data

  grafana:
    container_name: grafana
    image: grafana/grafana-oss
    ports:
      - 9091:3000
    volumes:
      - ./grafana-storage:/var/lib/grafana

  grafana-loki:
    container_name: grafana-loki
    image: grafana/loki
    ports:
      - 9092:3100
    volumes:
      - ./loki-storage:/mnt/config

volumes:
  prometheus-storage:

  alertmanager-storage:

  grafana-storage:

  loki-storage:
```

### prometheus.yml

```
global:
  scrape_interval: "1m"

rule_files:
  - prometheus_alerts.yml

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: "b2b-api-prometheus-metrics"
    metrics_path: /metrics
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["192.168.10.7:3095"]

  - job_name: "natlogs-node-exporter"
    metrics_path: /metrics
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["192.168.10.7:9100"]

  - job_name: "postgres-exporter"
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["192.168.10.7:9187"]
```

Comment: First, this question is offtopic for SO.

Comment: But here's a hint: remote_write is not supposed for you to implement. It is supposed to be used by prmetheus in agent mode. Normally in this situation you should deploy a separate instance of the prometheus in agent mode in the closed network, that will be scraping targets there, and writing scraped metrics to the main one.

Comment: @markalex Hi is there any other stackoverflow sites where I can post this kind of questions.

Comment: [su] or [sf]. [devops.se] too, but not sure 100%.
Also, don't forget to check their help sections, before asking.